# Are the "- if ... - else" command same with "if ... else" command in pug?

Tags: pug

There are two types of defining `if...else` logic in pug.

Option 1 (with `-`)

```
- var a = 5
- var content = {"b":"<style></style>"}
- if (content.b)
  div !{a} !{content.b}
- else
  div test
```

Option 2 (without `-`)

```
- var a = 5
- var content = {"b":"<style></style>"}
if (content.b)
  div !{a} !{content.b}
else
  div test
```

They both can deliver the same correct logic as I want. I just want to know whether they are the same? Why sometimes I have to add the `-` and sometimes I don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are almost the same.

- If you omit the hyphen, the parentheses around the condition(s) are optional.
- If you use a hyphen, the parentheses are required.

Otherwise there's no practical difference.

If you use a hyphen with `if`, you must also use hyphens with the sibling `else if`s and `else`. And vice versa. (Mixing hyphens and no-hyphens seems to work in some cases, but such code would be confusing, so just don't do it.)

The leading hyphen was required in Pug v1 (also called Jade). From [*Conditionals* in Pug docs](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html):

> Pug’s first-class conditional syntax allows for optional parentheses.
>
> If you’re coming from Pug v1, you may now omit the leading `-`. Otherwise, it’s identical (just regular JavaScript)

Valid:

```
// No hyphens -> no parentheses required
if foo
  p text
else if bar
  p text
else
  p text

// No hyphens -> parentheses are allowed
if (foo)
  p text
else if (bar)
  p text
else
  p text

// Hyphens -> parentheses are required
- if (foo)
  p text
- else if (bar)
  p text
- else
  p text
```

Invalid:

```
// Hyphens -> should use parentheses
- if foo
  p text
- else if bar
  p text
- else
  p text

// Mixing hyphens and no-hyphens -> invalid or at least confusing
if (foo)
  p text
- else if (bar)
  p text
else
  p text
```